# Datatables not showing data when searching is enabled

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I've a `DataTables` which get all the data available from an `AJAX` call which returns this:

[image]

I'm not using `serverSide` option 'cause I'm returning all the data in the first loading, but here the strange behavior: if I disable `searching`, as this:

```
let tablePrematch = $('#table-prematch').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: false,
    searching: false,
    deferRender: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    colReorder: true,
    pageLength: 100,
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
```

The `DataTables` correctly display the data. If I set `searching: true`, then `DataTables` won't display the rows.

This is weird 'cause the `AJAX` call actually returns the same response.

I just need to enable the search bar to filter specific columns, what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you debug when you  set  'searching: true'. Is it searching null or undefined by default that may not matches with table data.

Comment: @Mahi which do you suggest for debug?

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem you are describing, based on the information in the question. My DataTable example works correctly with `searching: true` and `searching: false` Can you provide a [mre]?